# NSImage Deprecated method: setFlipped replacement

Tags: objective-c, deprecated, nsimage

In the docs, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#jumpTo_17

It says `setFlipped` should be replaced with `drawInRect` -- but after looking through several examples and many failed attempts, I can't get my image to draw flipped using the arguments that are passed into `drawInRect`

Does anybody have experience, or know how to flip an image with the `drawInRect` method?  Or is there a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deprecation explanation was written with the expectation that `-setFlipped:` was being used to compensate for drawing right-side-up into a flipped view. That doesn't correspond to your use case where you're apparently trying to draw it upside-down, so the explanation doesn't help.

To draw upside-down, you should adjust the graphics context's transform using `NSAffineTransform`. The docs have a discussion of [creating a flip transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-BCIHDAIJ) to flip with respect to the whole view, but then you have to figure where to draw relative to that flipped coordinate system. I think it's easier to just translate the origin to the top-left of the destination rectangle, scale the Y direction by -1, then draw at (0, 0).

```
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

NSAffineTransform* xform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[xform translateXBy:NSMaxX(destRect) yBy:NSMinY(destRect)];
[xform scaleXBy:1 yBy:-1];
[xform concat];

[image drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(destRect), NSHeight(destRect))];

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a old question, but I was not able to use the above answer, and this was my solution:

```
NSImage *image...
[image drawInRect:destRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceIn fraction:1.0 respectFlipped:YES hints:nil];
```

Hope this can help someone :)